# Change roughness of one part of coloramp

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, color

Super quick question: I was wondering how to control the roughness of one part of this color ramp node. I'm trying to make the orange look like rust so I'd like to find out how to make the metal color smooth and metallic and the orange part have a high roughness and no metallic. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image: rust example]

Comment: You can probably use a similar (black and white) version of the same colorramp for the roughness and metallic inputs (invert the metallic one). Just remember that for roughness, black=shiny and white=flat. For metallic, black is non-metallic, white is metallic.

Comment: imma be honest i never though of plugging color ramp into other parts of the bsdf lol. Thanks for the tips :)

Comment: @Chris you can keyframe the colour and location of stops in a color-ramp, and all other fields.. although the use-cases for those seem pretty obscure...  :)

Comment: @RobinBetts: you are right. I thought i watched a video where the guy in the tutorial said that you couldn't do that....maybe i was halluzinating....

Comment: @Chris i seem to remember this wasn't possible previously